# Ribinitz or Riminitz Rebbe?

Tags: chassidic-rebbe

Is the Ribinizter Rebbe the same person as the Riminitzer Rebbe or is it two different rebbes? Is one of these pronunciations incorrect?

Comment: Just glancing at listings on the internet, the Ribnitzer Rebbe (ריבניצא) is referring to Reb Chaim Zanvill Abramowitz, zt"l. There are some websites referring to the "Rimnitz" which seem to be associated with Rabbi Moshe Tzvi Berkowitz, who served as a kind of Gabbai (personal valet) to Reb Chaim.

Answer (score 3):

They are the same person ([Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%96%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A5%27) suggests both pronunciations.) "Ribnitzer" is more common.

Answer (score 0):

Just glancing at listings on the internet, the Ribnitzer Rebbe ([ריבניצא](https://www.ribnitz.com)) is referring to [Reb Chaim Zanvill Abramowitz, zt"l](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Zanvl_Abramowitz). [His tzion is located in New York state, north of Monsey](https://www.google.com/maps/dir//Ohel+Hadmor+M%27Ribnitz/@41.1422767,-74.0694874,17z/data=!4m9!4m8!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c2dd0ce2fea5e3:0x4bd20a424c6f8b1e!2m2!1d-74.0667351!2d41.1416731!3e0?entry=ttu).

[Ribnitz is a town in the country of Moldova, west of Ukraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%AEbni%C8%9Ba).

There are some websites referring to the "[Rimnitz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unkkE7VuPsw)" which seem to be associated with Rabbi Moshe Tzvi Berkowitz, who served as a kind of Gabbai (personal valet) to Reb Chaim. He is called the *Mashbak MiRimnitz* on these sites. There is an amazing [video interview from Artscroll with Rabbi Berkowitz](https://inside.artscroll.com/up-close-with-the-ribnitzer-reb-moshe-tzvi-berkowitz/) explaining his connection with the Ribnitzer Rebbe which started when Rabbi Berkowitz was only a 14 year old boy. It is definitely worth watching.

The Mashbak is a *very soft-spoken* individual and during the interview, when he pronounces Ribnitz, his voice is so soft that the pronunciation of the "B" in Ribnitz is almost indistinguishable.